# Functions between G-set and H-set

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Consider a set $X$ with an action of the group $G$, and a set $Y$ with an action of the group $H$.

Consider now a function $f:X\to Y$. It makes no sense to talk about equivariance, since $G$ and $H$ are in general different. However we have an action of $G\times H$ on $Y^X$ (set of functions from $X$ to $Y$).

What can we say about this action? Is there a standard theory to study its behavior?

In particular, what if there are $g\in G,h\in H$ such that $fg = hf$?

Now suppose that $f$ is a *bijection* between $X$ and $Y$. This way $G$ can act on $Y$ (conjugating by $f$) and $H$ can act on $X$. What can we say? For example, what would be the kernel and the stabilizers of the $G\times H$ action in this case? Have things like these beens studied?

Any reference would also be welcome.

Comment: $fg=hf$ means $(g,h)$ fixes $f$, so this is a special case of computing fixed points, which is itself kind of a special case of computing stabilizers, which fully classifies a group action up to equivalence since every $G\times H$-set is equivalent to a disjoint union of orbits which are themselves equivalent to coset spaces. One way to describe the stabilizer of $f:X\to Y$ is the kernel of $G_1\times H_1\to{\rm Perm}\,f(X)$, where $G_1$ is the stabilizer of the partition of $X$ into fibers under $f$ (which has an induced action on $f(X)$) and $H_1$ is the setwise stabilizer of $f(X)$.

Comment: If we use a bijection $X\to Y$ to transport the action of $G$ to $Y$, there is no guarantee that the actions of $G$ and $H$ on $Y$ will commute, so no guarantee we get an induced action of $G\times H$ on $Y$, all we can say is we get an induced action of the free product $G\ast H$. Indeed we can get any possible $G\ast H$-set $Y$, if $X=Y$ and $X\to Y$ is the identity map and we restrict the action to $G,H$ as subgroups of $G\ast H$.